# How do I return multiple values from an async function to a synchronous context?

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-asyncio

I need to gather results from async calls and return them to an ordinary function--bridging the async and sync code sections confuses me.

First try, with an ugly inout param.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def one_call(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            txt = await response.text()
            return txt[0:20]


async def do_all(result_inout):
    urls = ["https://cnn.com", "https://nyt.com", "http://reuters.com"]
    out = await asyncio.gather(*[one_call(url) for url in urls])
    result_inout += out

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result_inout = []
    asyncio.run(do_all(result_inout))

    print(result_inout)
```

Second try,  but with direct use of the event loop, which is [discouraged](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) for application code.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # same imports, same one_call, same urls
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    aggregate_future = asyncio.gather(*[one_call(url) for url in urls])
    results = loop.run_until_complete(aggregate_future)
    loop.close()

    print(results)
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: In your first try, it should be `out = await aggregate_future` as you already have gathered the coroutines as `aggregate_future`. Also, there is no `result_inout` defined in function `do_all`.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the `aggregate_future` line. As to "There is no result_inout defined in function do_all" --  that is the parameter. But this is ugly, and I wonder  if there is a better way.

Comment: Hmmmm, I see now. You should return `out` from `do_all`, and append on the calling end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not need `result_inout`, you can just use `out = asyncio.run(do_all())` to get the `return res` of `do_all`.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def one_call(url):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return 0


async def do_all():
    urls = ["https://cnn.com", "https://nyt.com", "http://reuters.com"]
    out = await asyncio.gather(*[one_call(url) for url in urls])
    return out

if __name__ == "__main__":
    out = asyncio.run(do_all())

    print(out)
```

out will be `[0, 0, 0]`.